# How to convert rows to columns based on cloumn value in awk in unix

Tags: awk

I have data like below

```
dn: uid=032096,OU=Customers,OU=People,O=B2C
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: b2CCustomerPerson
cn: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
distinguishedName: uid=032096,OU=Customers,OU=People,O=B2C
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20110716120512.0Z
whenChanged: 20160407215618.0Z
uSNCreated: 401180
uSNChanged: 88288899
name: 032096
objectGUID:: B2QAeBHw1UKwFJAkKi8SFg==
pwdLastSet: 130528418341644345
objectSid:: AQUAABjdlU4Ng+r7Fsx63e/RO0CWfrW51Nqjtg==
objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,CN={C3B2C981-53A4-46FE-A3
 08-1CA306D4D63D}
dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000000.0Z
lastLogonTimestamp: 131045397771771108
b2CSmDisabledFlag: 0
b2CQALoginLockout: FALSE
b2CForgottenPassword24HrStartTime: 20140818092312.0Z
b2CSuffixCode: 00
b2CPwdNotSetup: FALSE
b2CSmPasswordData:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxG0G+3K7wga6Fd 6ujkLxkBaUEeEzCc8DmyfaKJTVn+QHNCaCq19TVZLhXVAEzoJGrTwY=
b2CWorkAddrDescriminator: US
b2CQALoginAttempt: 0
givenName: xxxxxx
title: 00
uid: 032096
b2CPasswordQuestion: 1xxxx
b2CBillingAddrDescriminator: US
b2CQALastLoginAttempt: 20140818132312.0Z
b2CDeliveryAddrDescriminator: US
b2CPasswordAnswer: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
b2CHomeAddrDescriminator: US
sn: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
b2CLastProfileChange: 20140818132312.0Z
b2CUserPrivacyConsent: 20071220171228.0Z
mail: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
b2CForgottenPasswordToken:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
dn: uid=03310326,OU=Customers,OU=People,O=B2C
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: b2CCustomerPerson
cn: xxxxxx
l: xxxxx
st: GA
postalCode: xxxxxx
distinguishedName: uid=03310326,OU=Customers,OU=People,O=B2C
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20120825012935.0Z
whenChanged: 20160122015941.0Z
uSNCreated: 8104543
uSNChanged: 81191393
name: 03310326
objectGUID:: a9Plz3ZBJE2XLjKzbi+jlA==
pwdLastSet: 129903317755454064
objectSid:: AQUAABjdlU4Ng+r7OCPkQBbSZU+kRb2ssiuk2w==
objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,CN={C3B2C981-53A4-46FE-A3
 08-1CA306D4D63D}
dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000000.0Z
lastLogonTimestamp: 130979015771278217
b2CSmDisabledFlag: 0
b2CQALoginLockout: FALSE
preferredLanguage: EN
b2CSuffixCode: 02
b2CSmPasswordData:xxxxxxxxxLZzGFgBmq2XPjD7qwXYAFl6e9G4jvQf6fMp306ksGE
EWEf9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
b2CWorkAddrDescriminator: US
middleName: A
b2CQALoginAttempt: 0
homePhone: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
givenName: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
title: 01
mobile: 3610625
uid: 03310326
b2CPasswordQuestion: xxxxxxxxxxxx
b2CBillingAddrDescriminator: US
b2CQALastLoginAttempt: 20130720213011.0Z
b2CDeliveryAddrDescriminator: US
b2CPasswordQuestion2: xxxxxxxxxxxx
b2CMobileAreaCode: xxxxxxx
b2CPasswordAnswer2: xxxxxxxxxxxx
b2CPasswordAnswer: xxxxxxxxxxx
b2CHomeAddrDescriminator: US
sn: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
streetAddress: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
b2CLastProfileChange: 20130720213011.0Z
b2CLastPasswordChange: 20120825012935.0Z
b2CHomeAddressZipCodeS4: xxxxxxxxxx
b2CUserPrivacyConsent: 20120825012935.0Z
b2CHomeAreaCode: xxxxxxxx
mail: xxxxxxxxxxxx
b2CUserProfileStatus: 201
b2COriginatingAppID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I need the output like

```
dn: uid=032096,OU=Customers,OU=People,O=B2C|objectClass: top|......
dn: uid=03310326,OU=Customers,OU=People,O=B2C|objectClass: top|....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste` to do that, like :

```
paste -d'|' -s filename
```

Comment: how can i get in multiple rows starting with dn:.....

Answer (score 0):

Try `awk` to achieve this :

```
awk '/dn/{if(b)print b;b=$0;next}NF{b=b "|" $0}END{print b}' filename > file.out
```

Comment: your code have bug, test your code with this text http://pastebin.com/ThX1R3H5

Comment: @Babyy: I tested it in my box, it gave the desired output which OP is asking. see [this](http://pastebin.com/gZLCvGte). what bug did you find ?